# Google CSE returns different results with same query?

Tags: node.js, google-custom-search

Why does Google's CSE return different results for the same query string?

Just to be clear, I'm not trying to reproduce the results of the actual Google search engine. I just want to get consistent results from Custom Search.

I'm using CSE for a practice project and I'm working on the pagination. When I submit the same request twice, changing only the value of the [`start`](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#start) parameter, I get vastly different `searchInformation.totalResults` values.

When I do a normal search for a random term (e.g. chickens) that returns millions of results, the difference between requests is millions.

When I do a crazy search devised to return only relatively few results, the difference is enough to change the number of pages of search results significantly.

Here's an example crazy search: chickens malaysia competition -masterchef serama bbc facebook

If I run it once, it may return 40 results. If I go to the "next page" of results (increment the `start` parameter by 10), it may say 49 results... or 21 results... It's all over the place.

Why would this be happening?

Here's a subset of  my code (node):

```
function cseSearch (req) {
  let searchType = req.query.searchType
  let cseId = process.env['CSE_ID_' + searchType.toUpperCase()]
  let start = req.query.page ? (req.query.page * 10) - 10 : 1
  if (start < 1) start = 1

  let options = {
    uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1/',
    qs: {
      q: req.query.query,
      cx: cseId,
      key: process.env.API_KEY,
      num: 10,
      safe: 'high',
      start: start
    },
    json: true
  }

  return rp(options)
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results.searchInformation)
      console.log(results)
      let pages = Math.floor(results.searchInformation.totalResults / 10) + 1
      let data = {
        searchType: req.query.searchType,
        searchTime: results.searchInformation.formattedSearchTime,
        resultCount: results.searchInformation.formattedTotalResults,
        items: results.items,
        pages: pages
      }
      console.log(`pages: ${pages}`)
      return data
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      return error
    })
}
```

- `rp()` is the [`request-promise-native`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) module.
- My CSE project is set up without specifying any domains and using the `Thing` schema.

You can find the whole thing at https://github.com/VAggrippino/findIt but it's still pretty rough.

Answer (score 0):

Since google uses so many servers/clusters, it's not likely that you will get a consistent result each time. For this reason you must specify the start parameter each time as if it is a new query.